# Custom Soap Header in asmx web serrvice

Tags: web-services, soap, asmx, soapheader

In an existing web service application(asmx services) I need to add new service which will be called through SOAP(java client), and it looks some thing like this

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:pus="http://www.example.org/pusheventservice/">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <pus:WSSecurity>
            <Credentials>
                <Username>someuser</Username>
                <Password>somepwd</Password>
            <Credentials>
        </pus:WSSecurity>
        <PUS:ServiceHeader>
            <PUS:TransactionID>101</PUS:TransactionID>
            <PUS:TransactionDate>2014/12/21</PUS:TransactionDate>
            <PUS:TransactionTime>14:54</PUS:TransactionTime>
```

I Inherited class `class ServiceHeader: SoapHeader` having username,password, TransactionId... and mention `[SoapHeader("userCredentials", Direction = SoapHeaderDirection.InOut)]` with WebMethod.
but my resultant soap message is not be same as above.

What are the steps need to be done..

Comment: For future readers: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: Did you read [`SoapHeader` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapheader.aspx)?

Comment: I cant use WCF now, I have to continue in asmx only

Comment: That's why I said "for future readers"

Comment: I read SoapHeader Class, I need to add tags <WSSecurity><Credentials>..... also <ServiceHeader><TransactionID>.... in soap header element.

Comment: So, what does your SOAP header look like now? Post the current header XML. Also, post the current `ServiceHeader` class.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <ServiceHeader xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <TransactionID>string</TransactionID>
      <TransactionDate>dateTime</TransactionDate>
      <ChannelTimeZone>string</ChannelTimeZone>
    </ServiceHeader>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68407/discussion-between-vishwanath-mishra-and-john-saunders).

Comment: Post your current XML and your current class _in your question_. Click the "Edit" link.